# Core Animation in Interface Builder

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, core-animation

So, I'm working on a mac app, and I'm trying to add a shadow via core animation to a button. I used the effects pane in Interface Builder and set the shadow and color, and made sure to check the "Want's Core Animation Layer" checkbox. But when simulating the interface or building the app, there is no shadow. I would appreciate it if someone knows what's wrong.

Thanks!

Edit: I've tried several things, including cleaning the project and turning on and off core animation. Nothing fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I ended up going through every interface element in the tab view and turned off core animation on each one (I had some strange transparency stuff going on). Then I went back to add the shadow, and it worked fine.